# Using Min & Max of an Interval in a replacement

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, replacement

I want to use a replacement rule to transform a list of equations.  The following works as expected:

```
eqns = {x'[t] == 2 y[t], y'[t] == -3 x[t]};
eqns /. (var_'[t] == rhs_) -> {var, rhs}
(* {{x, 2 y[t]}, {y, -3 x[t]}} *)
```

Now I want to use the same idea to get the `Min` and `Max` of an `Interval` associated with each variable.

```
range[x] = Interval[{-1, 1}]; range[y] = Interval[{-2, 2}];
eqns /. (var_'[t] == rhs_) -> {Min[range[var]], Max[range[var]]}
```

Since `{Min[range[x]], Max[range[x]]} = {-1 ,1}`, I expected to get

```
(* {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}} *)
```

but instead I get

```
(* {{Interval[{-1, 1}], Interval[{-1, 1}]}, {Interval[{-2, 2}], Interval[{-2, 2}]}} *)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `:>` instead of `->`. Notice `Min@aaaa` evaluates to `aaaa`. :)

Comment: @xzczd Yep, it was that easy.  Thanks!

Comment: @xzczd  Any rule of thumb when to use `:>` vs. `->` in this context?

Comment: Well, personally I don't recommend deciding it based on rule of thumb. Just think about if the right hand side can be/should be evaluate before pattern matching. `->` evaluates the right hand side instantly, while in this case, `Min[range[var]]` will evaluate to `range[var]`, so the right hand side should not be evaluated before the pattern matches. You may use `Trace` to check the evaluation order.